# HTML jQuery form submits more and more times each time you click submit once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

The title of the question is not extremely clear.

Below is the HTML

```html
 <button id="btn-documents-add">Add Documents</button>
 <div id="documents-form" title="Upload Document" style="display:none;">
   <form id="form-documents" action="/documents/save_document" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" id="document" name="document" /><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload !" /><br>
   </form>
 </div>
```

and the javascript (assuming jQuery and jQueryUI are loaded)

```
var openDialogDocuments = () => {
  let documentsDialog;
  documentsDialog = $("#documents-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Cancel: function() {
        documentsDialog.dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: () => {},
  });
  documentsDialog.unbind("submit");
  documentsDialog.find("form").on("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let xhr = $("#form-documents").ajaxSubmit().data("jqxhr");
    xhr.done((response, status, xhr) => {
      $("#messages-documents").html(response);
    });
    xhr.fail((err) => {
      $("#messages-documents").html(err.responseText);
    });
    xhr.always((xhr, status) => {
      $("#documents-form").dialog("close");
    });
  });
  documentsDialog.dialog("open");
};
$(function() {
  $("#btn-documents-add")
    .button()
    .click(openDialogDocuments);
});
```

The first time you clik on the "Add Documents" button the webpage makes only one call to the correct url. Second time you click on the button without reloading the page, it submits it 2 times. Third time, 3 times and so on...

I have tried to play around with the `.unbind("submit")` method I found in other answers but since I do not understand what it does I am not quite sure where to put it or even if it's the right solution.

I have put everything in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/ervz2n7f/) for your perusal.

All help welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unbinding from the wrong element when you do

```
documentsDialog.unbind("submit");
```

You need to remove the listener from the form inside `documentsDialog`

Change:

```
documentsDialog.unbind("submit");
documentsDialog.find("form").on("submit", (event) => {
```

To

```
documentsDialog.find("form").off('submit').on("submit", (event) => {
                           // ^^ remove any previous listener 
                           //    before adding new one
```

Note that `unbind()` is deprecated so we use `off()` instead

Comment: This is a better (more complete) answer.